# Custom Data Type Filter - Any Numerical Type

Tags: haskell, filter, custom-data-type

```
import System.IO()

data Point = Point
    { pointX :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double  -- ^ X coordinate
    , pointY :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Double  -- ^ Y coordinate
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Polygon = Polygon
    { points :: [Point]
    , yvalue :: Int
    } deriving (Show)
```

1. create a file `test.hs`
2. copy the two custom data type definitions above into it
3. open ghci and type `:l test.hs`
4. enter this test case:

   ```
   *test> let a = Polygon {points = [Point {pointX = 0.0, pointY = 0.0},Point {pointX = 4.0, pointY = 0.0},Point {pointX = 4.0, pointY = 2.0},Point {pointX = 4.0, pointY = 4.0},Point {pointX = 0.0, pointY = 4.0},Point {pointX = 0.0, pointY = 2.0},Point {pointX = 0.0, pointY = 0.0}], yvalue = 2}
   ```
5. Then:

   ```
   *test> let x = filter (<=(fromIntegral (yvalue a)).pointY) $ points a
   ```

You get the following error:

```
* couldn't match type `Point` with `Point -> c'
  Expected type: [Point -> c]
    Actual type: [Point]
* In the second argument of `($)', namely `points a'
  In the expression:
    filter (<=(fromIntegral (yvalue a)) . pointY) $ points a
  In an equation for `x':
    x = filter (<=(fromIntegral (yvalue a)).pointY) $ points a  
* Relevant bindings include
    x :: [Point -> c] (bound at <interactive>:92:5)
```

Comment: You mean like `filter ((>= someThreshold) . pointY)`?

Comment: That got me closer. I added the polygon structure. That changed the error to: Couldn't match type `Point -> c0' with `Point'
      Expected type: [Point]
        Actual type: [Point -> c0]

Comment: Can you paste the current code together with the known types of the identifiers you use for context?

Comment: I think that edit should include the only thing missing. There is a different line returning the perimeters.

Comment: The definition of `periFilter` in your question is incomplete; please edit it to fix that.

Comment: It probably is an easy syntax problem; it's just hard to confirm without a [mcve]. But you didn't do what I said: `let threshold = fromIntegral (yvalue x); ... filter ((>= threshold) . pointY)`

Comment: Note: file was modified to provide better test case, perifilter was not required to recreate problem.

Comment: melpomene, Li-yao Xia, and duplode thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is:

If you wish to filter by a specific numeric data type field then you just have to implement an instance of compare.

In my case:

```
instance Ord Point where
    compare x y = compare (pointY x) (pointY y)
```

This set the specified field I wished to compare by to be pointY which was already an instance of Double.

I was then able to use the following filter:

```
filter(\x -> x > Point {pointX = 0.0, pointY = (fromIntegral(yvalue))} $ points a
```

Note: that the pointX in this filter is strictly irrelevant.

There may be another solution which arises as there are some brilliant Haskell Programmers here, but this one works.

Comment: If no other solutions are added in 2 days, I will mark as answered.

Comment: That `Ord` instance is very much not well-behaved, in particular `Point 1 0 < Point 0 0` and `Point 1 0 > Point 0 0` would both be `False`, though these two points are clearly not equal. 2D points just do not form a proper `Ord` instance. — Why don't you use `filter ((<fromIntegral yValue) . pointY) $ points a`?

Comment: why not simply `filter (\ p -> pointY p > fromIntegral yvalue) $ points a`, without the one-off (and bogus) `Ord` instance.

Comment: leftaroundabout that sounds like what I started with, almost exactly and it wouldn't compare the point to a double. I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Will ness your solution works naturally and is definitely better. I was doing what I was doing, because I've been doing haskell for about 2 weeks. So if you write it up I would select it answered, though it doesn't look like you need the points. I couldn't find anything that simply showed how to access a numerical value for comparison.

Comment: That lambda by the way was the first one I've ever written.

Comment: It would be nice to have explained where if appropriate to use an instance of ord would be. If you have a link you trust to explain it well for a newb!